# Joomla-paypal How to show an agreement during between the selection of payment and redirection to paypal

Tags: php, redirect, joomla, paypal, payment

I have four membership package and each of them have two payment option like 6 month and 12 month but as the laws forces to show an agreement during an e-commerce I need to show the agrement after the user select the type of duration and membership. How to know which package is selected and wich option before redirection to paypal since the price will be in that agreement. How can I solve this.

Comment: are you using an extension from JED or have you developed it yourself?

Comment: I am developing my own extension.

Comment: You will need to provide a lot more detail so we can make sensible suggestions — e.g. code, the extensions logic flow otherwise your question is too broad.

Comment: You are right but I couldn^t found a way to explain with more detail. There was't any code written at the time I have written this question here but I think I solved and found a way to do what I want. Let me explain below.

Answer (score 0):

My form has four dorpdown selectbox with two options of each and those buttons are created by paypal button menager. Then I have written a jquery code for the proccess like following;

```
<script>
var packageForm,canBeSubmitted = false;
jQuery(function($) {
    $('form').on('submit',function(e){
        if(canBeSubmitted == false){
            packageForm = $(this);
            e.preventDefault();
            var on0 = $(this).find('input[name="on0"]')[0];
            var os0 = $(this).find('select[name="os0"] option:selected')[0];
            var dur = $(os0).val();
            on0 = $(on0).val();
            os0 = $(os0).text();           
            os0 = os0.split(' ');
            $('span.package').text(on0);
            $('span.duration').text(dur);
            $('span.price').text(os0[2]+" "+os0[3]);
            SqueezeBox.setContent( 'adopt', $('#agreement').html());
            SqueezeBox.resize({x: 800, y: 600});
        }
    });
    $('body').on('click','.accept',function(){
        if(packageForm == 'undefined'){
            alert('Select a membership.');
            return false;
        }
        console.log("accepted");
        canBeSubmitted = true;
        SqueezeBox.close();
        if(canBeSubmitted == true){
             $(packageForm).submit();
        }
        return true;
    });
    $('body').on('click','.deny',function(){
         console.log("denied");   
         SqueezeBox.close();
    });
     $('body').on('click','#printAg',function(){
        $(this).siblings('div.inner').addClass('printable');
        console.log("printable");
        $('div.printable').printThis({
                                    debug: true,              
                                    importCSS: true,           
                                    printContainer: true,      
                                    loadCSS: "<?php echo JURI::root(true);?>/components/com_dratransport/assets/css/print.css",
                                    pageTitle: "<?php echo JFactory::getConfig()->sitename; ?>",             
                                    removeInline: false        
                           });
    });
});
```

The form is the form which contain the paypal button. A hidden div is placed somewhere in the page with a text which contains span tags with classes to be captured by the jquery to change the content.

Form is prevented to be submitted. And the div is adopted in the squeez box after the content/(agreement text about the payment) is change with the selected button's informations. The if accept button is clicked form continue to be  submited, if deny is clickt modal box is closed without doing anything.